# How can I stop the "quick shot" feature in XCOM 2 Tactical Missions?

Tags: xcom-2

So I just started playing XCOM 2 recently (I'm still on the Gatecrasher mission, no spoilers please!)  But I've noticed a really annoying "feature" where I click on the "fire" icon and my solider *immediately fires on one of the visible enemies* - without giving me the chance to select my target, if multiple targets are visible.

So far it hasn't screwed me, as my men have always ended up shooting the target I intended to shoot at anyway, but it scares me to think they might one day shoot the wrong guy.  (I did get screwed by a grenade throw though - my soldier ended up throwing the grenade off into the weeds without giving me a chance to position the blast radius over the enemies I actually wanted to hit.)

I haven't had much luck finding information on this "feature" or how to disable it online, although I did find [this Reddit thread,](https://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/49zlsy/psa_priority_targeting_no_longer_arranges_targets/) which at least suggests it's a feature rather than a bug.  I gather that there's a keyboard shortcut (by pressing "1" twice) that will do this for the enemy with the best chance of being hit.  But this happens when I click (once) on the fire icon with the mouse (maybe it's registering two clicks really fast, by mistake?)

**Does anybody have any information about this "quick shot" feature, or how to stop it from triggering?**  I'm okay with solutions that disable the feature entirely as well as those that would stop it from happening on mouse-clicks alone.  I like taking my time to choose who I'll shoot at. =)

For the time being I'm training myself to use the number keys to select actions, as it's easier to ensure only one keypress that way.  This may very well end up being a solution in itself, but I'm accustomed to using the mouse from XCOM: EU/EW, and I'd like to continue doing it that way.

**PS:** I'm not a "modder" by any means, but I'm comfortable enough with computers and such that I'm also willing to hear ideas that involve editing .ini files and such, if anyone knows a way to accomplish this goal by playing with those settings.  Not my favourite solution, but acceptable for this purpose.

Comment: Not sure I've ever seen this, as it would somewhat remove the tactical elements of the game.  The only time I haven't been presented with a choice of target is when only 1 has been available.   It's worth noting that just because you can see a target, doesn't mean your soldier can see them.

Comment: How old is your mouse? Could it be, that you're involuntary double clicking?

Comment: There is no quick-shot feature.  I'd guess your mouse or keyboard is to blame.  Try switching them out and see if it still happens.

Comment: My mouse isn't brand new, it's true, but it's not known for sticking in other programs either.  I can hear it audibly click when I press the button and I only hear one click.  I'll try different one and see if that helps, though.  The keyboard isn't misbehaving for me, (just as well since it's a laptop) - it's just not my preferred input for this particular task.

Comment: @MattR I'm aware of what you're saying.  My soldiers have definitely had more than one visible target when this happens.  Also, remember the grenade I mentioned - it skipped right over letting me position the blast radius and just threw the grenade off screen as soon as I clicked the "frag grenade" icon!  Grenades always (are supposed to) let you position where you'll throw it, enemies or no enemies.

Comment: @Steve-O that sounds like your mouse may be accidentally double clicking (especially the grenades)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There is no such "feature".**

Clicking the cross-hair icon always has the camera zoom-in close to your character and present you with a list of targets to switch between, along with some details on the odds in question.  Clicking the same cross-hair icon again will confirm and fire, as will clicking the large confirmation button or pressing the enter key.  **You are likely accidentally double-clicking,** possibly **due to a bug** that some users claim to have experienced.  There are [some Steam discussions](http://steamcommunity.com/app/268500/discussions/0/371918937288086701/) on the subject here, although no consensus on the solution has been found.  One individual suggested that [this](http://download.cnet.com/Left-Mouse-Button-Fix/3000-2094_4-75863800.html) update to drivers specific to Razer mice might be a solution, assuming that only Razer mice exhibit the issue.

Comment: This is likely the truth, although it's annoying.  I don't have trouble with unexpected double-clicks in any other programs on my computer (not even XCOM EU or other Steam games.)  Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a way to fine-tune mouse sensitivity for clicks.  Thank you for your time. =)

Comment: @Steve-O Looks like this has happened to other people:  http://steamcommunity.com/app/268500/discussions/0/371918937288086701/

Answer (score 4):

While I agree with the other answer that this is not game-related, I do want to mention that one of the first parts of a mouse that starts failing is the little plastic "spring" (it's not really a spring) that enables clicking the mouse button.

When that little plastic breaks or changes shape, the mouse can register double click. This has happened to the last 3 mice that I didn't lose or break some other way, and seems like a mouse's "dying of old age".

Is there anything you can do? Well, buying a new mouse is the obvious solution.

However, you could also set up **AutoHotKey** for this. If the mouse is firing click events twice, these will happen in incredibly quick succession. There is a way to set up AutoHotkey in a way that it will ignore any mouseclick that is preceded by another recent mouseclick (you can configure the time).

But I would suggest confirming whether the mouse is faulty by using it on another computer and seeing if the problem reproduces itself (e.g. click on youtube video. If doubleclick registers, it should maximize the window instead of pause the video).
If it is the mouse, I would suggest simply replacing it instead of clever trying to temporarily work around the issue.